# Estimating gas cost programmatically while minting NFT in web3.js

Tags: javascript, web3js, nft

I am building an NFT minting dapp, I used a template and it seems like the gas limit is fixed in the configuration file, however, I want to be able to estimate the fee on the go. I found [.estimategas()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas) but I am not sure how to incorporate it into my function. Here is my mint function:

```
const claimNFTs = () => {
let cost = CONFIG.WEI_COST;
let gasLimit = CONFIG.GAS_LIMIT;
let totalCostWei = String(cost * mintAmount);
let totalGasLimit = String(gasLimit * mintAmount);
console.log("Cost: ", totalCostWei);
console.log("Gas limit: ", totalGasLimit);
setFeedback(`Minting your ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME}...`);
setClaimingNft(true);
blockchain.smartContract.methods
  .mint(blockchain.account, mintAmount)
  .send({
    gasLimit: String(totalGasLimit),
    to: CONFIG.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
    from: blockchain.account,
    value: totalCostWei,
  })
  .once("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    setFeedback("Sorry, something went wrong please try again later.");
    setClaimingNft(false);
  })
  .then((receipt) => {
    console.log(receipt);
    setFeedback(
      `WOW, the ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME} is yours! go visit Opensea.io to view it.`
    );
    setClaimingNft(false);
    dispatch(fetchData(blockchain.account));
  });
```

With this code, the gas fees seem to be very high, I just want to make sure I am not missing anything that may be driving the gas fee so high.

Comment: Have you implemented the `estimateGas` function? What's the number you get back?